# How to customize IBM Watson Assistant result from Search skill query

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery, watson-assistant

We have created an IBM Watson Assistant service as PLUS plan and integrated IBM Watson Discovery with it using the Search skill option. We are able to get the response from Discovery through Assistant but the results we got have many passages and we want to display only top 1 or 2 answers.

We are not finding any option to customize from Search skill. How can we customize the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Watson Discovery filter syntax to the query results. There is some mention of it in the [Troublshoot section of the Search skill documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-search-add#skill-search-add-troubleshoot).  You may want to apply the **count** operator whichh is described in the [Watson Discovery docs on building queries](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/discovery?topic=discovery-query-parameters#count).

Comment: ,thanks for your reply. I tried adding count:2 parameter in Dialog filter option and now I am not getting any results form discovery, if i remove count i am able to get results ..

Comment: Try without count but with other filters

Comment: I tried with confidence score still its not working.

Comment: You can try the different filters within your discovery instance first, in the "Build Queries" section/tab. - try natural language + More Options. Once you have working queries + filters here you can transfer them into your conversation "search skill" dialog node. You can see the query in the summary window within discovery, and as an example count=x is one of those fields.

Comment: @timd, thanks for your reply. I tested in discovery service and i am able to see exact answer/data for my queries and same thing i have added in conversation but i am not getting proper response. its still showing 3+ options as answer

Comment: Hi can you let me know which parameters/filters/etc you are trying, in discovery and then in conversation, and I can check myself in my own instance. Thanks